# Clarification on Prediction with a Regression Model using Centered Variables

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction, regression-coefficients, centering

As I understand it, for a regression model, centering the variables around their means can be helpful since it makes the intercept term the expected value of $Y_i$ when the predictor variables are set to their means.  So let's say I do a regression using centered variables and obtain coefficients $\beta_i$ and an intercept $\alpha$.  If I wished to do prediction on out-of-sample data, can I directly use these coefficients or do I need to use coefficients obtained from running a regression on non-centered data?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficients from centered and non-centered data will be identical, so you can use the same coefficients. However, the intercept will be different, so you will need to center the new observations around the *old* center.

That is, if you fit a regression with the predictor $X' = X - \bar X$, where $\bar X$ is the mean of the sample you used to fit the regression (aka the "training sample"), you need to subtract the old $\bar X$ from new observations before making predictions.